# UI Darkened Corners + React Native

Tags: css, menu, react-native, shadow

Attempting to get the following effect (darkened/shadow upper left corner effect). Any ideas? Currently I have resorted to using a png with the effect within it.

[image]

Here is what I have now (with dark corner menu png):

[image]

Comment: Is the effect on the first photo too?

Comment: no - its just permanently in the corner of the window